# Does google Drive api support 2 legged oauth?

Tags: oauth, google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace, 2-legged

Now, we have an application with Google Docs Api and 2 legged oauth. However,we want to migrate to Google Drive Api which uses Oauth 2.0.

Can we use 2 legged oauth with Google Drive Api?
Is there any example?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Service Accounts: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: How is consumer key from Google Apps domain https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#tokensGADomains used in Service Accounts?

I think Service Accounts can only be used, implemented in Third-party software vendors schema for 2-legged Google Apps.

Comment: Claudio, Can you describe how to use the Google Drive API with a Google Apps Marketplace App?  How do we use service accounts in this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

I just started looking into this and if I have any luck I will provide more info.

However, if you are using 2 legged oauth so you can work with google apps domain-wide then there is a published guide. I believe this is what the other answer was talking about.

Blog post explaining domain wide delegation: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/domain-wide-delegation-of-authority-and.html

Guide for the drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: Thanks Bachmann, but we know how to use the domain-wide delegation for the doc list api already.  We're looking to use the Google Drive API for our app in the Google Apps Marketplace, which, from all I can see only gives us OAUTH 2-legged credentials.  The Google Drive API only uses OAUTH 2.0, which does not support 2-legged credentials.  I'm looking for a way, perhaps something that I overlooked, to use credentials from the Google Apps Marketplace to access Google Drive.